# how to find does not match item by regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have comma separated values in my table column and I have to separate new values from the old ones.

My code is

```
    $a = '1,2,3,4';
    $b = '1,2';

    if(preg_match("/[^$b]/",$a,$matches)){
        print_r($matches);
    };
```

I want to find `3,4` , but I can't do it.

Comment: Do you really want regular expressions?

Comment: what's the logic behind?

Comment: Please make it clear what do you want with this code?

Comment: i have database field I have to separate  new value to older value and send message to newer value

Comment: Using regular expressions for that is flawed, because numbers don't work well in a string context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't use regular expressions for that. PHP has good functions to calculate intersections:

```
$a = explode(',', '1,2,3,4');
$b = explode(',', '1,2');

print_r(array_values(array_diff($a, $b)));
```

See also: [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff)

Note that this would also work for the following example:

```
$a = '1,2,3,4';
$b = '1,3';

// outcome must be: 2, 4
```

Comment: @Jon Maybe an anti anti-regex ambassador :)

Comment: Unfortunately there are quite a few of those ><

Comment: @Farhad And this one will continue working no matter how high the numbers go. ^^

Comment: @Farhad Not just "also works", it's the only correct way to handle sets.

Comment: @Jack you are right . if $a = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' it will also show correct answer , but another answer by mohsenipur will not work

Comment: In my opinion: Because the first version of the answer was quite short, non-self-explaining. That's changed now. Also, the question specifically asks for Regular Expressions. In my opinion this solution (this answer) is way better, but I also see that the questions asks for Regex ;-)

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen Thanks for reversing your vote :) wanting regex and needing regex aren't the same thing, and in this case would have had pretty disastrous results; I love regex, but knowing when not to use is worth its weight in gold ;-)

Comment: @Jack I agree. I'd have solved this issue with your solution too, maybe just mis-interpreted the question or the way it should be answered.

Answer (score -2):

use `preg_match_all` instead of  `preg_match`

```
$a = '1,2,3,4,10';
$b = '1,2';
if(preg_match_all("/[^$b](.*)/",$a,$matches)){
    print_r($matches);
};
```

output

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3,4,10
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ,4,10
    )

 )
```

Comment: @Farhad This will break once your values go above 9.

Comment: It will now fail for `$b == '1,3'`.

Comment: @mohammadmohsenipur not efficiently or consistently - only for a specific test case.

Comment: The answer for `$a == '1,2,3,4'` and `$b == '1,3'` should be `'2,4'`.